# fastify reply: treat null as undefined

Tags: json, typescript, fastify

When working with Java, annotation `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` causes null values to be omitted from the final JSON output.  For example, object `{a: 5, b: null}` is serialized to `{a: 5}`.

Fastify/Typescript already behave similarly on undefined values.  For example, object `{a: 5, b: undefined}` is serialized to `{a: 5}`.

But is there a way to get Fastify/Typescript to work similarly on null values?  Currently, object `{a: 5, b: null}` is serializing to `{a: 5, b: null}` instead of `{a: 5}`.

My solution so far has been to individually inspect fields and replace null with undefined, but this is cumbersome and error prone.  Hoping to find a cleaner solution!